# Externalizing properties for Mail plugin in Grails

Tags: email, grails, groovy, configuration-files

I want the Grails' Mail plugin to read configuration properties from external properties file in class path. I have added this line in Config.groovy,

```
grails.config.locations = [
            "classpath:app-${grails.util.Environment.current.name}-config.properties"]
```

and I have put properties in that file like this,

```
grails.mail.host = smtp.gmail.com
grails.mail.port = 465
grails.mail.username = username
grails.mail.password = password
```

all this work fine. The problem is that, the Mail plugin requires one more property that is of type Map. If we put that property in Config.groovy, I looks like this,

```
grails {
    mail {
        props = ["mail.smtp.auth"                  : "true",
                 "mail.smtp.socketFactory.port"    : "465",
                 "mail.smtp.socketFactory.class"   : "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory",
                 "mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback": "false"]
    }
}
```

Now if I put this in external file as following,

```
grails.mail.props = ["mail.smtp.auth"                  : "true",
                     "mail.smtp.socketFactory.port"    : "465",
                     "mail.smtp.socketFactory.class"   : "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory",
                     "mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback": "false"]
```

than it does not work. I need to read props Map from external file. I have searched a lot but in vain. Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You can load configuration from external `*.groovy` file where you can have maps etc. like in `Config.groovy`. Create for example `mail-config.groovy` with content as below:

```
grails {
    mail {
        host = smtp.gmail.com
        port = 465
        username = username
        password = password
        props = ["mail.smtp.auth"                  : "true",
                 "mail.smtp.socketFactory.port"    : "465",
                 "mail.smtp.socketFactory.class"   : "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory",
                 "mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback": "false"]
    }
}
```

And point Grails to use it:

```
grails.config.locations = ["classpath:mail-config.groovy"]
```